# Grid ordering best practice on websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, web-applications, datagrid

The question relates to the way in which rows are ordered in a grid when each column has an ascending or descending sort button. We're wanting to develop this in a way that is "industry standard" or "best practice".

Say we have four columns:  Region,  Country,  Town,  Street.

The user wants to sort by Country and then Town.

Do they:

1. Click the sort button on Town followed by Country or
2. Click the sort button on Country followed by Town

In many ways the former is easier to develop because each time a sort is clicked we can simply bring it to the front of the list, keeping about three in the list.

Is there even a standard way of doing it, if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way of doing this that I know of, and you would most likely want to use an third party library to achieve it. It is a very complex process to create a functional grid UI so two libraries that you might want to look at is [JqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and Telerik's [Kendo UI grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) examples. The JqGrid is a free third party library and Telerik lets you trial their libraries.

For multiple sorting with kendo UI you can find it in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/grid/walkthrough#sorting) and JqGrid is in the same link under searching/filtering multiple fields for the example click on the search icon and with it should give you an option to search by multiple columns. 
Here is a image from the JqGrid multiple column search/filtering example to better explain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fassetar. In both of the examples you posted when a sort option is chosen (i.e. click on the column heading) only that column is used for the sort. The previous sort is dropped completely. Essentially we're wanting to sort by at least two columns (preferably 3). We've got the technology working nicely in that we can sort like those examples, we know what we need to do (or we think we do) to implement sorting on multiple columns.

Comment: Sorry I've updated my answer and you will find documentation on how to achieve this for the Kendo UI Grid. As for the JqGrid the link does include an example in "Search Multiple Fields Search: Search Controls (datepicker, autocomplete, dropdown, checkbox, custom, etc)